# Receiving POST and calling same php by PUT

Tags: php, post, put

I have a php page where I receive by post an id called **rfc**, however, after a few operations I call the same page again, which was originally invoked by a POST but now int he form I set it to be by PUT, so at start of php I have something like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT') {

    $pedidos = array();

    echo $_PUT['rfc'];

}

else {

    include("connectDB.php");
    $mySQL = new MySQL();
    $rfc=$_POST['rfc'];
    ......
```

First time I get to the page from the form submission with POST, al happens OK, but when I do the PUT, at same page, error log says:

> Undefined index: rfc[...]

I thought the is else block would solve this but it doesn't.

This is my form where I do the PUT:

```
echo "<form action=\"checkout.php\" method=\"PUT\">";
    foreach ($pedidos as $key => $value) {
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"pedidos[]\" value=\"$key\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cantidades[]\" value=\"value\">";
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rfc\" value=\"$rfc\">";
    }
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Confirmar\">";
```

Line where it claims to be undefined is actually the one from the implicit POST block.

Comment: $_PUT['rfc'] is not set, try to print_r($_PUT); to see if any of the $_PUT array is set at all. I also hope you read my message in the earlier thread about things you should fix up.

Comment: I don't think PUT is meant to be used the way you use it

Comment: "Line where it claims to be undefined is actually the one from the implicit POST block." - so, the request method is *not* PUT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `$_PUT` doesn't exist. You need a little more work to get PUT data. You essentially need to use:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input')
```

(thanks @Jack)

Comment: Or simply `file_get_contents('php://input')`.

Comment: @Jack, very true, I've update the question.

Comment: But WHY does the error goes right to the block where it's not supposed to *get*

Comment: I'm still getting same eror.

Comment: Because $_PUT does not exist, as it's stated at the beginning of the answer

Comment: Of course I had changed it and got same error. I decided to go for doing a POST to another `.php`